# Ambiguous overload call to 'Create` (but not 'Foo')

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I have an example class with two class functions `Foo`. One takes an argument, the other doesn't:

```
TContoso = class
   class function Foo: IUnknown; overload;
   class function Foo(bar: IUnknown): IUnknown; overload;
end;
```

And i can call my static function without incident:

```
unk := TContoso.Foo;
```

But if the methods were named what i wanted to call them in the first place:

```
TContoso = class
   class function Create: IUnknown; overload;
   class function Create(bar: IUnknown): IUnknown; overload;
end;
```

Then the same class method call:

```
unk := TContoso.Create;
```

fails to compile:

> Ambiguous overload call to 'Create'

Why is the non-ambiguous call ambigious? I hope it's not an arbitrary thing.

## Why would you do that?

Not that it matters to the question, but if we ignore the question and focus on the situation i'm in, some would recognize the pattern:

```
CoXmlWriter = class
   class function Create: IXmlWriter; overload;
   class function Create(const stream: ISequentialStream): IXmlWriter; overload;
end;
```

Comment: Could you make stream an optional parameter and drop it down to one Create function?

Comment: @alcalde I could do a lot of things. Although don't confuse the question with the example. In reality i have four creates `Create()`, `Create(IStream)`, `Create(ISequentialStream)`, `Create(filename)`, `Create(TStream)`.

Comment: I wonder why you call a class function Create. Maybe making these constructors is a way around the problem.

Comment: Just following the pattern the other 768 Co classes inside the VCL and Delphi's code generator. In the end I gave up, and heroes the compiler resolve the ambiguous calls by giving then unique names (Create, CreateWithFoo, CreateWithBar, CreateWithBah)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the ambiguity is with the constructor declared in `TObject` that has identical parameters.

However, in modern versions of Delphi the code compiles. And I think that is right because the `TObject` constructor is not marked with `overload`. So this feels like a Delphi 5 compiler bug.

Comment: Oh god, now i remember. [Once you introduce an `overload`, the ancestor constructors leak in](http://wiert.me/2010/11/02/interesting-delphi-questions-on-stackoverflow-by-ian-boyd-in-constructors-methods-and-directives/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Contoso = class
   class function Create: IUnknown; overload; reintroduce;
   class function Create(bar: IUnknown): IUnknown; overload;
end;
```

(or perhaps switch around overload; and reintroduce; modifiers)

Comment: Yeah, nothing can fix it. i had a [series of questions a few years ago](http://wiert.me/2010/11/02/interesting-delphi-questions-on-stackoverflow-by-ian-boyd-in-constructors-methods-and-directives/). It's just a fundamental limitation of the compiler.